# Regular Expression match after = to end of the line for first line that is not commented out

Tags: .net, regex, expression

I need to match any text that comes after the '=' sign to the end of the line for a line that is not commented out. Can you suggest a regular expression that would work for this?

```
Example:
  // Username = admin
     Username = [any text here should match regex]

  // Password = password
     Password= [any text here should match regex]
```

**Updated with following example:**

```
One more example just for clarification:
  // FilePath = //test/test/test.log
     FilePath= //test/test/test.log
```

Anything coming before the "=" will be word or group of words. Anything else can/will be ignored.

It shouldn't matter if there is a space or not between the word and "=". I have not been able to implement the "or" clause yet but this is the current regular expression I am trying to get to work. If you have a better solution or can help update my regex to work im game for either:

```
Different permutations:
 (?<=Username=).+
 (?<=Username =).+

 (?<=Password=).+
 (?<=Password =).+
```

**SOLVED:**
Thank you for all the examples and quick responses/help. The following two regular expressions fit my situation the best depending on whether I am wanting all matches after "=" or single match after "=" based on a specific word before the "=".

```
^\s*\w+\s*=\s*(.+)$       // Returns all matches
^\s*Username\s*=\s*(.+)$  // Returns a single match for a specific field
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
^\s*\w+\s*=\s*(.+)$
```

Here's an example that uses this regex:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string line = "     Username = [any text here should match regex]";

      Regex r = new Regex(@"^\s*\w+\s*=\s*(?<text>.+)$");
      Match m = r.Match(line);
      if (m.Success)
         Console.WriteLine(r.Match(line).Result("${text}")); 
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should mention that you expect that the "variable" in front of the `=` sign to be a "word" character and that everything else is discarded...

Comment: Ok. I have tested this and it works great giving me all the matches, however im thinking instead of returning ALL matches, for my situation i would just want to return the first match of "Username =" or "Username=" that is uncommented. Could you suggest what the easiest way to do this is?

Comment: Perfect! I think this is going to give me just what I need! Tested and working so far! Really appreciate your solution!

Comment: I just tried to run the above regex's not just in a regular expression tester (which worked fine) but in my actual application which uses .Net. It does not seem to return a match. Do i need to modify the above regular expressions to work with the .Net engine?

Comment: Also just tried to run the above regular expressions using this regular expression editor and they did not return a match... http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde I added an example.

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde It also worked on regexhero.  I used the regex `^\s*\w+\s*=\s*(.+)$` with the string `Username = [any text here should match regex]`.  The results show 1 match and 1 group. Maybe I misunderstood your question.  Are you doing something different?

Comment: This does work. It was a bug in my implementation of the regular expression within my code. Thanks for your help David.

Answer (score 1):

This should to the trick:

```
^\s*(?!//)\w+\s*=\s*(.*)
```

What it says is this:

`^` Beginning of line

`\s*` Any number of whitespaces

`(?!//)` No comment

`\w+` At least one word character (should be extended if other characters are allowed in variable names)

`\s*` Any number of whitespaces

`=` egal sign

`(.*)` the rest of the line (in a group, so you can extract the value)

Comment: Wow your fast! I'll give this a try and see if it covers what i need! Could you also give me the regular expression that would find anything in front of the = sign?

Comment: Nice start but `\W` isn’t whitespace and the negative assert is followed directly by word characters, i.e. it won’t trigger if there’s space(s) between the commend and the word.

Comment: This matches text in commented-out lines.

Comment: Ok. I have tested this and it works, however im thinking instead of returning ALL items, for my situation i would want to just return the first match of "Username =" or "Username=" that is uncommented. Could you also reply to this comment with that regular expression as well? This would cover all the different situations where I will need to use this regular expression!

Comment: `^\s*(?!//)Username\s*=\s*(.*)`

Comment: @Markus The assertion forbids `//` *direct in front of* the word. It doesn’t forbid it with space in between (e.g. `//  foo=bar`). Now, in the current form of the regex that doesn’t matter since the only thing allowed to come before the word is spaces anyway. But now the assertion is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This one would work only if the code is separated by newline

```
^\s*[^\\]+\s*=(.+)$
```

Use the `multiline` option

works [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^/]*=(.*)$
```

Text will be matched into backreference \1.

Failes if single / is found.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it with the following (I'm using the `$` matches line breaks option as well):

```
Section\:(?:[^\:]*(?:=.*)?\n)*\s*Field\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

- `Section` is the section identifier
- `Field` is the field identifier
- won't match fields in the wrong section
- first capture group will contain everything after the equals sign minus leading and trailing whitespace
- literal colons are allowed in value names but not key names
- ignores commented fields
- ignores blank fields

You can test this on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) with this stuff:

```
AnotherSection:
     SomeField = x
     AnotherField = y
Section:
     SomeField = Z
     AnotherField = Q
     TricksyBlankField
     Field
     // ^ this field is blank
  // Field = ignored because I'm a comment
     Herp = : <-- literal colon
     Field =        (everything in the parentheses get captured)        
     ExtraStuff = something
```

RegexPal doesn't show group matching, but it is there.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Ill have to look regexpal up.

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde: I linked to it. its between the code block and the bullet list.